# Web Application Frameworks

Tags: web-applications

I just wanted to get a sense of what web application frameworks is used by users of stackoverflow.com either at work or for personal projects.

Please list the name of the web application framework and the platform it is based on.

Comment: All the cool programmers make their own frameworks from scratch, and copy and paste the code between projects /s

Comment: Polls should be Community Wiki

Comment: Seriously, what useful information do you expect to get from this question?

Comment: Perhaps to work out what's popular, go away and learn it, thus increasing his employment prospects in what seems to be the predominant platform rather than focussing on something too niche?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to know?

Comment: Ben...It is a CW question. 

y experience in doing web development is limited to ASP.NET & DotNetNuke,So I just want to know what else is popular outside of .NET Platform.

Comment: How could this question be subjective & argumentative. All I asked is the name of the web-app framework that the users of this use. That is a straight forward question, Besides as you can see, none of the 4 answers given below were argumentative.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)  (Python)
2. [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)  (Ruby)
3. [Symphony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) (Php)
4. [Cake](http://cakephp.org/) (Php)
5. [Zend](http://www.zend.com/) (Php)
6. [Grail](http://www.grails.org/) (Java)
7. [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) (Java)

Are some of the most popular frameworks at the moment but I'm using [Playframework](http://www.playframework.org/) because I like it more.

Answer (score 1):

Big fan of [QCodo](http://www.qcodo.com) myself

Answer (score 1):

We use 
1) [JSF(Java)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/)
2) [Seam(Java)](http://seamframework.org/)
3) [Struts(Java)](http://struts.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There are different Frameworks for different Programming Languages.

I prefer:

1. ASP.NET MVC (.NET)
2. PureMVC (For Flash and Flex)